# keytool -genseckey -alias TDES -keyalg DESede -keysize 128 works within jre/bin folder but not when the keytool.exe is on another location

Tags: java, cryptography, keytool

I would like to create a TDES key with size 128bits and hence I have used the keytool to generate the jceks with the following command. When I run the same under the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin` folder I can see that the execution succeeds and the jceks is created. However when the export the keytool.exe to another location perhaps the desktop, I can see that the same command fails with the following error.

```
C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\KeyGen>keytool -genseckey -alias TDES -keyalg DESede -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore TDES.jceks -storepass change -keypass change
keytool error: java.security.InvalidParameterException: Wrong keysize: must be equal to 112 or 168

C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\KeyGen>
C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\KeyGen>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. My application refers to the keytool.exe and generates a jceks with chosen parameters like above.

On further research I can see that it works only on Java 1.8.0_25 and but even when I run the same command that succeeds on the 1.8.0_25 under the 1.8.0_60 /bin, I get the following error...

Here is the log from the verbose output under Java 1.8.0_60

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin>keytool -genseckey -alias TDES -keyalg DESede -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore TDES.jceks -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -v
keytool error: java.security.InvalidParameterException: Wrong keysize: must be equal to 112 or 168
java.security.InvalidParameterException: Wrong keysize: must be equal to 112 or 168
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeKeyGenerator.engineInit(DESedeKeyGenerator.java:94)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:517)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:494)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doGenSecretKey(Main.java:1528)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:969)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

Here is the successful Log from the 1.8.0_25

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>keytool -genseckey -alias TDES -keyalg DESede -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore TDES.jceks -storepass changeit -keypass changeit -v
Generated 128-bit DESede secret key
[Storing TDES.jceks]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>
```

Comment: Is the keytool.exe referred to in your System's path variable a different one ?

Comment: Nope, both are the same. I double checked that, in fact I copied it out of the bin folder.

Comment: Does it work with key size 112 ?

Comment: 3DES with 128 bit keys is just 3DES with 112 bit key without the parity bits. You should be able to create the key that you want.

Comment: I just tried it with specifying 168 and it worked. I did not include a keysize in the options for keytool and it worked. I suggest you take a revised look at what is required by keytool to do that. Because as @ArtjomB.mentioned, the parity bit info is correct. (168 bit key needs 32 bit parity, 112 bit key needs 16 and 56 bit key needs 8)

Comment: I tried the same with both 112 and 168 options, either way it executes without errors but the keysizes created in both the cases is 192 bits. But the original question still remains a mystery because when I tried to create both 192 and 256 bit keys with DESEDE, I was able to do them when running the keytool from the bin folder. The keystore files generated did have the correct key length, 192 and 256.

Comment: That's kind of funny as 256 bit TDES keys should not be possible. Are you sure you are not specifying AES? Note that Java will also work with DES keys without parity set correctly (the `SecretKeyFactory` will however correctly set parity).

Comment: As you can see both the cases of 192 and 128 succeed. However I just tried it on the latest jre 1.8.0_60 and it gives the same error there. For now, I can see that the below command works only on jre 1.8.0_25


C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>keytool -genseckey -alias TDES -keyalg DESede -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore TDES.jceks -storepass changeit -keypass changeit

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when the `keytool.exe` changes location it will use the default JRE instead of the one where it is kept. Older Java versions only supported three key TDES (ABC) keys of 192 bits (168 bits effective) and not two key TDES (ABA) of 128 bits (112 bit effective).

Note that if you follow NIST requirements that you *should* use TDES keys of 168 unrelated bits. 112 bit DES has a security margin lower than 84 bits so it is not considered secure anymore.